# Counting classname in a specific div area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need work in different div sections with same classnames.. so I need to work each div area specially...At last :

Question: here is the sample that only the area I want gie alert to me... but classname it counts for all in page.. I wanna the code only count in first area...

Alerting 2 = false what I want "Alert 1" as  document.getElementsByClassName("aaa").length...

```js
$(document).on("click","div#deneme_1 #deneme", function() {
var classayisi  = document.getElementsByClassName("aaa").length;
alert (classayisi);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div id="deneme_1"> <input class="aaa bbb" value="kkk"> <button id="deneme">try 1</button> </div>
<div id="deneme_2"> <input class="aaa bbb" value="nnn"> <button id="deneme">try 2</button> </div>
```

Comment: so select the div and then select the elements. It is odd that you are mixing jQuery and DOM

Comment: Ah, you want the siblings.... not the children of what was clicked.

Comment: ids are SINGULAR so you should not have two buttons on the page with the same id

Answer (score 1):

So you need to select the siblings of the button. JQuery has a siblings method. Vanilla JS you can select the parent and find the elements in it.

```js
$(document).on("click","div > .deneme", function() {
  var siblings  = $(this).siblings('.aaa');
  console.log(siblings.length);
  
  var siblings2 = this.closest("div").querySelectorAll('.aaa');
  console.log(siblings2.length);
  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div id="deneme_1"> <input class="aaa bbb" value="kkk"> <button class="deneme">try 1</button> </div>
<div id="deneme_2"> <input class="aaa bbb" value="nnn"> <input class="aaa bbb" value="nnn"> <button class="deneme">try 2</button> </div>
```

Comment: I thought you were clicking on the div, not the button. Altered the code

Comment: Thanx for answer.. I use that too in my codes but much more efficent is that code I will write down as an answer..

Comment: unsure how your code is so more efficient when it is basically the same thing as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for :

find "classnames" in "idnames" section , or div , or i tag etc...

```
$(this).closest('#idname').find(".classname").length;
```

Comment: Um, if you are going to select by an id, then there is zero reason to even use closet. And it is no different than my answer. I just used generic "div" for closest to make it work on both elements and not have a hard coded id. It would have been 100x better if you had a class on it and can select it by class.

Comment: it is cause , I use create elements tags so in few step div segment lose.. but id never changes... That is why..

Comment: but also yes I will try to delete closest , ı understand your logic.. Thank you very much also, you lead me to find solution.